# Is it necessary to watch "The LEGO Ninjago Movie" to appreciate "The LEGO Movie 2: The Second Part"?

Tags: suggested-order, the-lego-movie-2-the-second-part, the-lego-ninjago-movie

As a direct codicil to [Can I watch "The LEGO Movie 2: The Second Part" without watching the first one?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97048/can-i-watch-lego-movie-2-without-watching-the-first-part)

Is ***The LEGO Ninjago Movie*** required watching before seeing ***The LEGO Movie 2: The Second Part***?

I thoroughly enjoyed *The LEGO Movie* and *The LEGO Batman Movie*, and I understand there is some follow-on to the plot elements of these. 
Can the same be said for *The LEGO Ninjago Movie*, or is it a different universe/timeline?

Comment: I have watched all of them, but I thought that _The LEGO Movie 2: The Second Part_ was only really a followup to the story in _The LEGO Movie_.

Comment: LEGO Ninjago and **The LEGO movie** is two different movies far as I know. wikipedia states that *The Lego Movie 2: The Second Part (known in some countries as The Lego Movie 2) is a 2019 computer-animated adventure comedy film produced by the Warner Animation Group and distributed by Warner Bros. Pictures. A direct sequel to The Lego Movie (2014), it is the fourth film in the franchise, following the release of two spin-offs, The Lego Batman Movie and The Lego Ninjago Movie (both 2017). Animal Logic, who provided the animation for all the films in the franchise, returned.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, No.

The Lego Movie Part 2 makes the odd reference to other Lego films (such as Batman doesn't go off with the other DC characters at the beginning because he's "having another adventure"). You only really need to see the first Lego Movie as it continues on from the end of the first.